# ssh from docker gets stuck without any error

Tags: ssh, docker

I tried to ssh from a docker container to internet but it gets stuck without any error. I ran ssh in verbose mode and this is the result:

```
root@bac91c5282c7:/opt# ssh -v git@git.foo.com -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to git.foo.com [xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

My problem is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278341/ssh-from-docker-container-to-internet-got-stuck-and-no-errors-produced) but there the problem was that the bridge was improperly configured since `Gateway` and `IPAddress` were empty. But in my case, everything seem correct. I can also telnet to any port I want on any remote machine. The problem is related to `ssh` specifically.

```
foo@bar:~/code$ ip addr | grep "docker"
7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
```

docker network:

```
foo@bar:~/code$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
e8f23bd035df        bridge              bridge              local               
b1eca300de29        host                host                local               
aa7945003010        none                null                local               
c6ac46615046        code_default    bridge              local
```

output of `docker inspect`:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "77e0a4431cdd656605591d2cff40c0a68d811cb700066f047b9d4a241d4634be",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/77e0a4431cdd",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "90c7ff3ddeab7ac6287d56fb6aaec81252a8f15c95fb65921f7872bd7bf8eb70",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "5c0c33b6892d197a30fff6d806999698705615c62fd35229e9477e9658783548",
                    "EndpointID": "90c7ff3ddeab7ac6287d56fb6aaec81252a8f15c95fb65921f7872bd7bf8eb70",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It's worth mentioning that this problem occurs only on a particular server. I've tested this container on my laptop or VPS but ran into no problem.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like MTU problem in virtual network.

Comment: @Jakuje What's the problem exactly and how can I fix it?

Comment: It is explained for example [here](http://www.snailbook.com/faq/mtu-mismatch.auto.html). I explained this in the question on [SU](http://superuser.com/questions/1082529/strange-ssh-connection-issue).